# Drupal OAuth Service Module

Tags: drupal, authentication, module, oauth

I am trying to do some research into potentially setting up an existing Drupal site with user accounts/login page to also be an OAuth service provider, basically authenticating users to make calls with a web service. I am looking for a Drupal module which will give this functionality. Most of what I run into are OAuth consumer modules, which is not what I want in this case.

I've found a few modules which I think *might* do this for me, but the module descriptions are generally pretty vague and don't have much of a user base which doesn't inspire much confidence.

Has anyone else done this before? What are the best modules available for doing this?

Comment: For OAuth2, the corresponding Client is [OAuth2 Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/miniorange_oauth_client). There's also [OAuth server](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth_server_sso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of research I was able to find a few modules which help with this. Namely, Services http://drupal.org/project/services and it's accompanying OAuth authentication module http://drupal.org/project/services_oauth.

Both of these have several dependencies as well. Once configured you can authenticate users on third party sites using OAuth. Supposedly, this exposes a whole Drupal API web service, but I am yet to get that to work successfully.

Comment: Have you had any success here?  I tried setting it up, but I keep getting "The consumer is not authorized to access this service." In D6 I setup a dummy user and then a single consumer.  Then I call oauth/request_token add in the response tokens and get the consumer authorized the I get the access token and summit the signed request.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you should be using "services", version 3.x, and "oauth". You won't want to use any of the other modules. They are not compatible with the latest services and oauth modules.

Answer (score 1):

For OAuth2, there's [OAuth2 Server](http://drupal.org/project/oauth2_server).  [OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth) is for OAuth1.

The corresponding client for OAuth2 is [OAuth2 Client](https://drupal.org/project/oauth2_client).